# ExpressJS/Mongodb POST request and losing user data

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, ejs, mongojs

I have a NodeJS app, and I am trying to add a 'New Ticket' feature to my users profile page.

Here is how the flow should work -
  1. User submits a request which creates a new ticket in my mongodb 
  2. the profile page reloads and shows the newly created ticket in the 'Recent ticket' section. (I am having no trouble retrieving the previosuly created tickets)

however when I submit the post request and try to reload the profile page, I lose the user data. (i.e. user is not defined).

```
router.post('/addTicket',  [
    check('phonenumber', 'user phone number required').not().isEmpty(),
    check('requestDevice', 'A device is required').not().isEmpty(),
    check('userDescription', 'A brief description is required').not().isEmpty(),
], function(req,res,){
    var userDescription = req.body.userDescription;
    var requestDevice     = req.body.requestDevice;
    var phonenumber = req.body.phonenumber;

    const result = validationResult(req);
    var errors = result.errors;

    if (!result.isEmpty()) {
        res.render('profile', {

                errors: errors,
                requestDevice: requestDevice,
                userDescription: userDescription,       
        });
    } else {
        console.log(phonenumber);
        var newTicket = {
            id: Math.random().toString(36).substring(2),
            requestDevice: requestDevice,
            userDescription: userDescription,
            openDate: Date.now(),
            closeDate: "",
            techComment: "",
            status : "open",
        }

        User.updateOne( {phonenumber: phonenumber }, {$push: {"tickets":  newTicket  } }, false, function(err, doc) {
            if(err){
                    res.send(err);
                } else {
                    console.log('ticket Added...');
                    res.redirect('/profile', {user:req.session.user}); //I know this req.session.user usage is probably not correct, but I've just been trying everything.
                }
        });


    }
});
```

and my console

```
    ReferenceError: D:\users\admin\desktop\from laptop\itspot.v.1.0.0\views\profile.ejs:59
    57|     <div class="w3-display-container w3-center w3-mobile" style="height: 300px">
    58|         <div class="w3-display-middle w3-card-2 w3-center" style="margin-top: 25px; width: 35%" >
 >> 59|            <h4 class="w3-center">Welcome <%= user.name.fname  %> !</h4>
    60|            <p class="w3-center"><img src="../img/avatar.png" class="w3-circle" style="height:106px;width:106px" alt="Avatar"></p>
    61|            <hr>
    62|            <p> <i class="fa fa-home fa-fw  w3-text-theme"></i> Zip: <%=user.zipcode %> </p>

user is not defined
    at eval (eval at compile (D:\users\admin\desktop\from laptop\itspot.v.1.0.0\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:633:12), <anonymous>:29:26)
    at returnedFn (D:\users\admin\desktop\from laptop\itspot.v.1.0.0\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:668:17)
    at tryHandleCache (D:\users\admin\desktop\from laptop\itspot.v.1.0.0\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:254:36)
    at View.exports.renderFile [as engine] (D:\users\admin\desktop\from laptop\itspot.v.1.0.0\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:485:10)
    at View.render (D:\users\admin\desktop\from laptop\itspot.v.1.0.0\node_modules\express\lib\view.js:135:8)
    at tryRender (D:\users\admin\desktop\from laptop\itspot.v.1.0.0\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:640:10)
    at Function.render (D:\users\admin\desktop\from laptop\itspot.v.1.0.0\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:592:3)
    at ServerResponse.render (D:\users\admin\desktop\from laptop\itspot.v.1.0.0\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:1012:7)
    at D:\users\admin\desktop\from laptop\itspot.v.1.0.0\routes\users.js:337:11
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (D:\users\admin\desktop\from laptop\itspot.v.1.0.0\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (D:\users\admin\desktop\from laptop\itspot.v.1.0.0\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\users\admin\desktop\from laptop\itspot.v.1.0.0\node_modules\express-validator\src\middlewares\check.js:23:13)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at fulfilled (D:\users\admin\desktop\from laptop\itspot.v.1.0.0\node_modules\express-validator\src\middlewares\check.js:4:58)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
```

Here is the profile route

```
router.get('/profile', ensureAuthenticated, function(req,res){
    res.render('profile');
});
```

And just for the heck of it, this is my app.js file

```
var routes = require('./routes/index');
var services = require('./routes/services');
var users = require('./routes/users');
var info = require('./routes/info');
var admins = require('./routes/admins');

var app = express();

db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error'));
db.once('open', function () {
  console.log('db is connected');
});

app.use(helmet());
//view engine

app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

//set static folder
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use('/css', express.static(__dirname + '/node_modules/w3-css'));
//body parser
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
//Express Session Middleware
app.use(session({
    secret: 'this is super secret meow',
  store: new MongoStore({mongooseConnection: db}),
    saveUninitialized: true,
    resave: true,
  cookie: {
    httpOnly: false,
    secure: false,

  }
}));

//passport middleware
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

// Express Validator Middleware
/*app.use(expressValidator({
  errorFormatter: function(param, msg, value) {
      var namespace = param.split('.'), 
      root    = namespace.shift(),
      formParam = root;

    while(namespace.length) {
      formParam += '[' + namespace.shift() + ']';
    }
    return {
      param : formParam,
      msg   : msg,
      value : value
    };
  }
 })); */

// Connect-Flash Middleware
app.use(flash());
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.locals.messages = require('express-messages')(req, res);
  next();
});

//Access Globals
app.get('*', function(req, res, next){
  res.locals.user = req.user || null;
  next();

});



// Define Routes
app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/users', users);
app.use('/services', services);
app.use('/info', info);
app.use('/admins', admins);


app.listen(3000);
console.log('Server started on port 3000');
```

Adding Mongoose Schema

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        fname:{type: String, maxlength: 30, minlength: 1 },
        lname: {type: String, maxlength: 30, minlength: 1}
    },

    role: {type: String, default: "user"},

    email: {
        type: String,
        trim: true,
        lowercase: true,
        unique: true,
    },
    phonenumber: { type: String, required: true, validate: /^\d{10}$/, unique: true },
    zipcode: String,
    password: String, 
    devices: [],
    tickets: [],
    creationDate: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
    isVerified: {type: Boolean, default: false},
    passwordResetToken: String,
    PasswordResetExpires: Date,
});


const tokenSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    _userId: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, required: true, ref: 'User'},
    token: {type: String, required: true},
    createdAt: { type: Date, required: true, default: Date.now, expires: 43200 }
});

const Token = mongoose.model('Token', tokenSchema);
var User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);

module.exports = {Token, User};
```

Session Data that gets saved to my database

```
 db.sessions.find().pretty()
{
        "_id" : "e9bmD-yK2Rsr0fDajeusrtMTCJpUm0pT",
        "expires" : ISODate("2019-11-29T19:49:43.182Z"),
        "session" : "{\"cookie\":{\"originalMaxAge\":null,\"expires\":null,\"secure\":false,\"httpOnly\":false,\"path\":\"/\"},\"flash\":{},\"passport\":{\"user\":\"5dccd8041ac5ab2eec6f2be7\"}}" //This is the correct user ID, I checked it against the User id in the db.
}
```

Comment: Pass your `user` when render the profile page. `res.render('profile');`

Answer (score 0):

```
User.findOneAndUpdate( {phonenumber: phonenumber }, {$push: {"tickets": newTicket } }, {new: true}, function(err, doc) { if(err){ res.send(err); } else { console.log('ticket Added...', doc, 'this is updated data'); res.redirect('/profile', {user: doc});
```

Comment: I appreciate the response, but that does not solve the issue.

Comment: @Mdurocher are you getting the same error as before ?. And yes I saw you have defined user.username in ejs file but your user object dont have any field named username, so its data wont be available in user object

Comment: I updated the code and showed some more pieces of the app, not sure if it helps isolate the issue, I'm getting super frustrated, and I know it's going to be something simple that I'm over looking.

Comment: I see that you have used mongoose, so can you share the user schema , and also log the req.session to see if the session has any data or not, because i cant see any data being assigned to session in your code. Everything you are doing is correct, just not using the variables correctly, so just update the code with console data of session and doc => from user.updateone, and we can find the solution.

Comment: Ok, I added in the schema and session data that gets saved to my db.

Comment: @Mdurocher okay here's the issue....when you apply updateone....it returns only error or success document....so the data of the document is not available in the result of query......I am updating my answer....check it and let me know if it worked

Answer (score 0):

Instead of rendering the view try redirecting to the `/profile`  route

```js
db.users.update( {phonenumber: phonenumber }, {$set: {"tickets":  [newTicket]  } }, false, function(err, doc) {
                if(err){
                        res.send(err);
                    } else {
                        console.log('ticket Added...');
                        res.redirect('/profile'); // Change render to redirect

                    }
            });
```

Comment: gave it a shot, but no luck... I appreciate the response though.  I am still trying to find a way to send a post request, and reload the page to show the updates. (i.e. add a ticket and then show the newly added ticket)